# Is there anyway to fix the first output of count()?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a movie website and I want to count the links of each box but the first the count(); output is 0 and after that it will continue the real numbers and it's terrible this is my code:

```
<div class="links" style="display: none;">
                <?php 
                    $c = 1;
                    $post_something = $link['links'];

                    //This will count the number of links
                $number = count($post_something);


                foreach($post_something as $links){

                //This is the output of the count ?>
                  <p><?php  echo $number  ?></p>

                  <a class="download-button" href="<?php echo $links['link_of_field'] ?>">
                      <?php
                        if(!empty($links['name_field'])){
                            echo $links['name_field'];
                            $c++;
                        } else {?>
                            قسمت <?php echo $c;
                            $c++;
                            ?>
                        <?php }
                      ?>
                  </a>  
                <? }
                ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            <?php }?>
```

The problem is at the first it has the output of 0!

Here is the resault of var_dump

> array(6) { 
> [0]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E01_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } 
> [1]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E02_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" }
>  [2]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E03_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } 
> [3]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E04_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" }
>  [4]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E05_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } 
> [5]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E06_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } }
>   
> array(6) { 
> [0]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E01_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } 
> [1]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E02_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" }
>  [2]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E03_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } 
> [3]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E04_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" }
>  [4]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E05_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } 
> [5]=> array(2) { ["name_field"]=> string(0) "" ["link_of_field"]=> string(176) "dl/1/354830/4272/12426/303e08ccc88e2dd4428117619f226fe19a/series/game_of_thrones/Game_of_Thrones_S08E06_10bit_x265_720p_WEBRip_2CH_PSA_30NAMA.mkv" } }

Comment: Keys in an array always start at 0 and increment by one unless you customize the array to start at another number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, technically, in computer language, all counts start from `[0]` and not `[1]`. So there is nothing wrong with your code. It is working fine if it starts from 0.

This line `$number = count($post_something);` in your code should return the actual number of results returned.

Let me try to explain with an example;

In a code like this;

```
<?php
    $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
    $totalCount = count($cars);
    print_r($cars); // this will print Array ( [0] => Volvo [1] => BMW [2] => Toyota )
    echo $totalCount; // this will return 3
?>
```

so in the example above, the array prints from 0 but the count produces the number of items in the array which is 3.

I hope this clarifies things for you. If not am willing to explain further or sort this out with you.

Comment: Wait a moment! Actually I don't know why but It is in a foreach and the counter is in foreach. Can you try it in foreach?!

Comment: If you want the total results in an array, you do not need to do a `foreach`. Just call `count()`. If you use a `foreach` statement, your count will always start from 0 unless you customize it.

Comment: can u say how to customize it?! 'cause I have to put it in foreach...

Comment: you have to put what in `foreach`? be very clear what you want to achieve

Comment: There is too much things I have to be clear with you. I can't 'cause I don't kno whow to say them. Anyway thank you!